# Linux Shared Memory Segments: Mutex Assertion Error

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-memory

I have these 2 simple programs using shared memory in linux.

Data client:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("mem.share", "r");
if (fp<=0){
    cout<<"Error, cannot open memory link file"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
int shmid;
fscanf (fp, "%d", &shmid);  
fprintf(fp, "%d", shmid);
fclose(fp);
cout<<"Using the file share index #"<<shmid<<endl;
uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
if (buffer<=0){
    cout<<"Error, cannot link memory"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Data provider:

```
int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 140, 0666);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("mem.share", "w+");
fprintf(fp, "%d", shmid);
fclose(fp);
```

I run these two programs in this system, with no problem:

```
Armbian Buster with Linux 5.3.9-sunxi
/etc/os-release:
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
```

But, when i trie to run the programs in this system:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

I got this result:

```
Using the file share index #524304
outstation: pthread_mutex_lock.c:81: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
Aborted
```

These are the shared memory in the two systems (using ipcs -m)
Armbian:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 0          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 1          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 2          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 3          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 4          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 5          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 6          alfa       666        140        0
0x00000000 7          alfa       666        140        0
```

Raspbian:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 0          root       666        140        0
0x00000000 32769      pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 65538      pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 98307      pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 131076     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 163845     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 196614     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 229383     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 262152     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 294921     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 327690     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 360459     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 393228     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 425997     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 458766     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 491535     pi         666        140        0
0x00000000 524304     pi         666        140        0
```

Can anyone help-me to understand what I'm doing wrong? What is the diference between these two systems?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you use mutexes? I only see calling `printf` on file opened for reading.

Comment: I have found the problem, the Linux library version.